# Understanding Principal Component Analysis, I.T. Jolliffe

Tags: statistics

Reading Principal Component Analysis, Second Edition by I.T. Jolliffe.

Supposing we have a collection of $n$ samples $x_i$ of $m$ variables, with a known covariance matrix $\Sigma$ for a random vector $X$.

If I understand correctly, the principal components of $x_i$ are then scalars $z_k$ for $k=1, 2, \ldots, p$ where $ z_k = \alpha_k^tx_i$ such that overall $\alpha_k^tX $ has the maximum variance subject to being uncorrelated with $\alpha_1X, \ldots, \alpha_{k-1}X$, where the $\alpha_t$ are unit vectors.

He writes, to derive the form of the PCs, consider first $\alpha_1X$, the vector $\alpha_1$ that maximizes $var[\alpha_1^t X] = \alpha_1^t \Sigma \alpha_1$.

From what I understand, for the $n$ random vectors, $\alpha_1$ should be a unit vector which maximizes variance, which I think(?) means maximizing
$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(\alpha_1^tx_i - \bar{\mu})^2 }{n}$ where $\bar{\mu} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\alpha_1^tx_i}{n}$

I do not understand why $var[\alpha_1^t x] = \alpha_1^t \Sigma \alpha_1$

Any insights appreciated (additionally my notation might be a bit off, any corrections welcome).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we drop the index $1$ for simplicity:

$Var(\alpha \cdot x)=E[(\alpha \cdot x)^2]-E[(\alpha \cdot x)]^2$

Substituting $\alpha \cdot x=\sum_i \alpha_ix_i$ and expanding:

$Var(\alpha \cdot x)=\sum_{i,j} E[\alpha_i\alpha_j x_ix_j]-E[\alpha_ix_i]E[\alpha_j x_j]=\sum_{i,j}\alpha_i\alpha_j(E[x_ix_j]-E[x_i]E[x_j])=\sum_{i,j}\alpha_i\alpha_jE[(x_i-\mu_i)(x_j-\mu_j)]$

, which is the expression used in the book.